# How to convert date and time inside data frame to float64 datatype?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, data-science

I have this Excel file [data](https://github.com/Mohammed20201991/DataSets/blob/main/data.xlsx)
as in the image below [image]] following this [tutorial](https://kgptalkie.com/multi-step-time-series-predicting-using-rnn-lstm/) with data mentioned (https://i.stack.imgur.com/kbI7C.png)
I use colab notebook : by writing code down

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from numpy import nan

from tensorflow.keras import Sequential
from tensorflow.keras.layers import LSTM, Dense

from sklearn.metrics import mean_squared_error
from sklearn.preprocessing import MinMaxScaler
#Reading the dataset
data_path= "/content/data.xlsx"
data = pd.read_excel(data_path)
data.head()
```

When try to check all data columns type by using `data.info()` I got :

```
<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
RangeIndex: 84960 entries, 0 to 84959
Data columns (total 9 columns):
 #   Column           Non-Null Count  Dtype         
---  ------           --------------  -----         
 0   Time             84960 non-null  datetime64[ns]
 1   Fridge           84960 non-null  float64       
 2   Lights           84960 non-null  float64       
 3   Microwave        84960 non-null  float64       
 4   Pump1            84960 non-null  float64       
 5   Pump2            84960 non-null  float64       
 6   TV               84960 non-null  float64       
 7   Washing Machine  84960 non-null  float64       
 8   Total Load       84960 non-null  float64       
dtypes: datetime64[ns](1), float64(8)
memory usage: 5.8 MB
```

I am trying to convert Time type `datetime64` to `float64` by

```
# data = data.astype('float')
x = data['Time'].values.astype("float64")
x
```

but got this issue :

```
3632             except TypeError:
   3633                 # If we have a listlike key, _check_indexing_error will raise

KeyError: 'Time'
```

```
## What I am expect : 
<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
RangeIndex: 84960 entries, 0 to 84959
Data columns (total 9 columns):
 #   Column           Non-Null Count  Dtype         
---  ------           --------------  -----         
 0   Time             84960 non-null  float64
 1   Fridge           84960 non-null  float64       
 2   Lights           84960 non-null  float64       
 3   Microwave        84960 non-null  float64       
 4   Pump1            84960 non-null  float64       
 5   Pump2            84960 non-null  float64       
 6   TV               84960 non-null  float64       
 7   Washing Machine  84960 non-null  float64       
 8   Total Load       84960 non-null  float64       
dtypes: float64(9)
memory usage: 5.8 MB
```

The format of Time: dd/mm/yyyy hh:mm
[image]

Comment: to `float64` you mean to Unix Epoch?

Comment: Sorry I have not get what you mean ,but the reason for converting to float64 to make all columns with same data type

Comment: @Minh-LongLuu since the data is coming from Excel it might make more sense to use Excel's definition - the number of days since 1899-12-30.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try the below to convert:

```
data['Time'] = data['Time'].apply(lambda x: x.timestamp())
data['Time'] = data['Time'].astype('float64')
data.info()
```

Comment: still has the new issue with same reason : 
I am sharing notebook her https://colab.research.google.com/drive/15VgkH-hM50l3Xcc0FUdmuGHHK2VpM9SX?usp=sharing

Comment: can you run this code to ensure that the Time column exist data = pd.read_excel(data_path)
print(data.head()) ? 
Because the error says that the column does not exist

Comment: yes it exists as you can see in collab 
when typing data.columns  we get 
Index(['Time ', 'Fridge', 'Lights', 'Microwave', 'Pump1', 'Pump2', 'TV',
       'Washing Machine', 'Total Load'],
      dtype='object')

Comment: Ok there is possibility that there might extra name in the column name. Do this print(data.columns) get the column name then change via this line data.rename(columns={'Time ': 'Time'}, inplace=True) then try again. See how it goes

Answer (score 0):

The solution as @[Abedulmajeed](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1954048/abdulmajeed) said there was space with column name `Time`  changed to `Time`

```
print(data.columns)
data.rename(columns={'Time ': 'Time'}, inplace=True)
data['Time'] = data['Time'].apply(lambda x: x.timestamp())
data['Time'] = data['Time'].astype('float64')
data.info()
```